# Delphi XE4 iOS app works on simualtor but not on debug device

Tags: ios, delphi

I have the app showing its designated background image while app loads. It then crashes running this code at startup:

```
  // unzip own resources like images, data files ettc. 
  FAppDataDirPath := GetHomePath + PathDelim + Application.Title + '.app' + PathDelim;
  P := FAppDataDirPath + 'assets.zip';
  if FileExists(P) then
    begin
      Z := TZipFile.Create;
      try
        Z.Open(P, zmRead);
        Z.ExtractAll(FAppDataDirPath + 'Library');
      finally
        Z.Free;
      end;
    end
  ;
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: So does the `/private/var/mobile/Applications/blanked_out/blanked_out_also.app/Library/assets/app_bac` file or directory exist on the actual device?

Comment: It is puzzling to me. On simulator this path exists: "/private/var/mobile/Applications/exampleGuID/example.app/Library" but on iphone he **Library** part does not and can not be created?

Comment: @KenWhite : I have created a more specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809533/delphi-xe4-ios-how-to-get-library-path-on-actual-ios-device - I will be happy to accept answer and give bounty to you on this question (even if my problem is not solved, it is also a big help to be able to ask a more specific question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the wrong method to get the locations.

Switch to using [`System.IOUtils.TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.IOUtils.TPath), using [`TPath.GetHomePath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath) to get the home folder, [`TPath.GetDocumentsPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath) for the `Documents` folder, and [`TPath.GetLibraryPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetLibraryPath) to get the `Library` folder location.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I am currently using **GetHomePath** (plus the "Directory" part) which in the help is described as "On iOS, it points to the device-specific location of the sandbox for the application; the iOS location typically includes a local directory and a GUID." - I saw some examples on the net using this. I will try your solution later tonight.

Comment: See my last edit; my first answer was more difficult than it needed to be. You were headed in the right direction. :-)

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it sorted out. :-)

Comment: Gaaaaa I'm having issues on iOS devices on XE8, TPath.GetHomePath is returning a different path than even the XE8 documentation says it's supposed to be. All other platforms (including simulator) work fine.