# How to get "Library" path on actual iOS device

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

I am using the following code to my app base directory:

```
// /private/var/mobile/Applications/exampleID/example.app/ 
FAppDataDirPath := GetHomePath + PathDelim + Application.Title + '.app' + PathDelim;
// /private/var/mobile/Applications/exampleID/example.app/Library/
FAppDataLibraryDirPath := FAppDataDirPath + 'Library' + PathDelim;
```

On iOS simulator both these paths exist.

However, on the iOS device only **FAppDataDirPath** exists. The "Library" 
variation can not be created using e.g **ForceDirectories**

What is wrong? :(

Comment: I've posted an answer at [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17659477/62576) that may help.